# Find and replace question regarding RegEx.Replace

Tags: c#, regex, replace, find, wildcard

I have a text file and I want to be able to change all instances of:

**T1M6** to **N1T1M6**

The T will always be a different value depending on the text file loaded.  So example it could sometimes be

**T2M6**
 and that would need to be turned into
 **N2T2M6**.
  The N(value) must match the T(value).  The M6 will always be M6.

Another example:

**T9M6** would translate to **N9T9M6**

Here is my code to do the loading of the text file:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
```

Here is  RegEx.Replace statement that I came up with.  Not sure if it is right.

```
 content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(T([-\d.]))M6", "N1$1M6");
```

It seems to work at searching for **T5M6** and turning it into **N1T5M6**.

But I am unsure how to turn the N(value) into the value that T is.  For example **N5T5M6**.

Can someone please show me how to do modify my code to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Really???  If you don't have the data on 'N' from the pathology report, what is the advantage in synthesizing values of N based on T?  In the future, records will contain N but not to-date?  How will you distinguish values of N which were measured and values of N which were calculated this way?  It might be better to represent each of these in its own column, and output '-' for values that weren't recorded.  If you need to re-output with "calculated N" values, then you can do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"T([-\d.])M6", "N$1T$1M6");
```

Also, you should probably replace `[-\d.]` with `\d` or `-?\d\.?`

Comment: What does \d do that [-\d.] doesn't do?  With the change, would it look like: @"T(\d)M6", "N$1T$1M6"); ?

Comment: `\d` only matches digits; I have no idea what you're trying to match.  Yes, it would.